# Let me Understand How this Function Works (Python)

Tags: python, function, for-loop

Hello im Totally Beginner in Programming and i started learning python, and i want to understand this Function, i dont get How it Works:

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in "AEIOUaeiou":
            translation = translation + "g"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation

print(translate(input("Enter the Word: ")))
```

so what i understand the 'phrase' is an input, for example if we Write "dog" in that input, output will be "dgg" but i dont understand how this works, more so i dont understand this part:

```
if letter in "AEIOUaeiou":
            translation = translation + "g"
```

how this part makes "dog" convert to "dgg"

and this part:

```
translation = translation + letter
```

from where exactly translation variable gets a Value? and How that makes dog to convert to dgg?

i would appreciate anyone help me,thank you

Comment: "how this part makes "dog" convert to "dgg"" It does not, it just either appends the original letter to the translation, or a "g" for a vowel. The `for` loop does that for each letter in the original phrase.

Comment: Add some `print` statements to the code to see what the value of `letter` is at each step, what the value of `translation` is before and after each modification, etc.

Comment: Would it help you if I said you could replace the `if/else` statement with `translation = translation + ("g" if letter in "AEIOUaeiou" else letter)`?

Comment: Code like this is most easily understood by visualizing how the code is processed and data changes as you step through the lines. Enter or paste your code in [link](https://pythontutor.com/python-debugger.html#mode=edit) and watch it happening.

Comment: You can [visualize this code](https://pythontutor.com/render.html#mode=display) in action.

Comment: Thank you Mate for Answering my Question and Helping me! i Understood How this Code Worked by Running a code visualizer, but i understand now completely!

Another Question i have is how the Output is inline not like: d g g which code makes the output to be inline like "dgg"? i would appreciate if u explain this one also

Answer (score 0):

- In the function, you're passing a phrase `translate(input("Enter the Word: "))`
- Defined a blank string `translation = ""`
- Then you're going through each letter in the phrase. `for letter in phrase:`
- If condition checks if the letter is a vowel

  - If it is a vowel, concatenate `g` to `translate`
  - Otherwise, concatenate the same letter to the `translate`

Which is why your `dog` got translated to `dgg`

Comment: Thank you Mate for Answering my Question and Helping me! i Understood How this Code Worked by Running a code visualizer, but i understand now completely!

Another Question i have is how the Output is inline not like: d g g which code makes the output to be inline like "dgg"? i would appreciate if u explain this one also

Comment: because you are only concatenating the letter or `g` if the letter is a vowel. That's why `o` in `dog` got translated to `g`, with the final output as `dgg`. if you want `d g g`, you need to append a space after every letter.

Answer (score 0):

The translation variable is declared with the set value of an empty string.
After that the function goes over every letter and checks if it's a vocal (lowercase or uppercase "aeiou").
The translation variable, for every letter we go over, has assigned to itself its value (to avoid just overriding the string every time) and in case the letter il a vocal, places a "g" otherwise places the letter the input string had originally.
This causes the string "dog" to turn into "dgg" because the letter "o" is matched and replaced with a lowercase "g"

Comment: Thank you Mate for Answering my Question and Helping me! i Understood How this Code Worked by Running a code visualizer, but i understand now completely!

Another Question i have is how the Output is inline not like: d
 g
 g
 which code makes the output to be inline like "dgg"? i would appreciate if u explain this one also

Comment: The text does not go on multiple lines because it is only concatenated in the function, and only once the print function is called. If you wish to go on a new line every character you can add, after the else block in the loop, but still inside the loop, a newline character, like this: translation = translation + "\n".

Answer (score 0):

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in "AEIOUaeiou":
            translation = translation + "g"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
    return translation

print(translate(input("Enter the Word: ")))
```

if there is a word like "apple" in input (phrase). You replace the vowels with "g". So the for loop is iterating through the input you have and replacing vowels with "g". If the letter you have is not a vowel, it keeps the letter in the input. At the end "translation" returns the new word.

Comment: Thank you Mate for Answering my Question and Helping me! i Understood How this Code Worked by Running a code visualizer, but i understand now completely!

Comment: Another Question i have is how the Output is inline not like:
d
g
g
which code makes the output to be inline like "dgg"? i would appreciate if u explain this one also

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question completely, but I would assume it has to do with the ""

Answer (score 0):

This is simple, although I don't understand why someone would do this or what does it have to do with translation, but let's go with it anyways.

As you know, that `phrase` is an input which then you can work on and do what you want with it in the scope of the function. If you're not familiar with scopes, don't worry about it now. That's not important here.

So you get an input, which by default is of `string` type, then you take each character of the string and do something with it. What you are doing is simply this:

1- You define an empty string variable, for the purpose of filling it character by character later. You just provide the base for it in the beginning.

2- You check each letter of the input phrase. That's what `for letter in phrase` is doing. That takes each character of the phrase string and temporarily puts it in a variable names 'letter'.

3- If the current selected character of the phrase is any of these `"AEIOUaeiou"` characters (which is also being checked one by one using another for loop), then it will be turned into a `"g"`. Otherwise it will remain the same.

These characters `"AEIOUaeiou"` are the vowels of English language. So basically what this function is doing is changing any vowel into a letter `"g"`. I don't know why, but it is what it is.

Now how is the output of the function formed? You can run this to see step by step:

```py
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:
        if letter in "AEIOUaeiou":
            translation = translation + "g"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter
        print("The translation variable is now:", translation)
    return translation

print(translate(input("Enter the Word: ")))
```

I just added this `print("The translation variable is now:", translation)` at then end of each step of the loop so you see the outcome. You can do the same for any loop and variable if you want, to see what's happening. Although using print() decreases the performance, it is doesn't seem important right now.

Edit: Formatting edit. Ignore.

Answer (score 0):

So, I understand that you are able to figure out what the program is doing but not how the logic is built to do the task. The function replaces the vowels in the phrase with the letter 'g'. So this is implemented is that a for loop is run where every letter of phrase is taken. Then in the if condition the letter is checked if it is present in the string "AEIOUaeiou" which is basically the collection of vowels in caps and lowercase. And a new string called translation is constructed which is initially an empty string "". For each iteration in for loop, if the letter is vowel, 'g' is added at the end of the translation string or else the letter is added to the translation string.Hope you get it.